# how to fix "E:Unable to locate package firefox-mozilla-build"

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I want to install fire fox and after the typing these commands in terminal

```
apt-get remove iceweasel
echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" >| tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
apt-get update
apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build
```

I am facing an error

```
E:Unable to locate package firefox-mozilla-build
```

Comment: Any errors when you `apt-get update`? You check ` /etc/apt/sources.list ` to confirm repo was added?

Comment: no just this error.when i open the source list just i see deb http://downloads.sourceforge...../mozilla/apt all main

Answer (score 1):

Just run `dpkg -i firefox-mozilla-build` it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This will delete mozilla build,
Just run the below command.

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox-mozilla-build
```

Comment: Why are you saying to remove it when they're trying to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Check which packages the repository is publishing with this command:

```
awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }'/var/lib/apt/lists/*ubuntuzilla*Packages
```

There should be `firefox-mozilla-build`. If not, then the repository is not providing the package that you want to install.

Answer (score 0):

its been 8 months. I don't know whether my answer still good for you. You have to browse at `/etc/apt`.
If you find 2 file named `source.list` open both files. Copy the rest text in `source.list` that contains `deb/http://sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/apt all main` to another `source.list` file.
Then you have to run this code again: `apt-get update`
At last, run code: `apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build`